# PHP Uploading with FastCGI on IIS 7.5 stalling/taking forever

Tags: php, performance, iis, post, file-upload

Okay first off; this works 100% okay on one server set up, but is messed up on a very similar one - which is why I think it has to be an IIS issue somewhere - I just don't know where.

I have a very standard PHP upload script, but it keeps locking up/freezing then resuming itself on larger files (over 250mb.)

No errors return, and the upload does finish and work fine for files up to 4gb - but it takes forever. You can watch the size of the tmp files as they upload, and it will just stop receiving data - sometimes for several minutes at a time, then just pick back up right where it left off and continue the upload.

I have configured the following in IIS:

CGI:

- Time-out: 00:30:00
- Activity Timeout: 300000
- Idle Timeout: 300000
- Request Timeout: 300000

Request Filtering:

- Max allowed content length: 4294967295
- Max URL Length: 4096
- Max query string: 2048

PHP:

- post_max_size: 4G
- upload_max_filesize: 4G
- max_execution_time: 300000
- max_file_uploads: 300000
- max_input_time: -1
- memory_limit: -1

I was previously getting errors from the script taking too long, however upping the Activity, Idle, and Request times have fixed that issue. The uploads do work fine, but take FOREVER.
I have the exact same IIS settings on another dev box running the same upload script and it works flawlessly - so I don't know what I'm missing.

PHP is 5.4.14. I get nothing in the PHP error log or Windows Event Viewer (since no errors are actually thrown as far as I can tell.)

Anyone have any idea of what settings I could be missing somewhere?

Comment: are both of these servers located on the same network?

Comment: they are both accessibly to the outside world; and for testing purposes we have tried uploading from outside networks. the results are still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, that was stupid. I just asked around and someone did infact turn on "intrusion prevention" at the router level for the one server that was having issues. Disabling that seems to resolve the problem.